# how to know the configured container-runtime of used docker client

Tags: docker, go, containers, containerd, docker-engine

I would like to know how to findout the configured container-runtime of your docker-client.
Preferably in a programmatic way with golang.

I know those to packages for golang handling containers with containerd and docker-engine:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/containerd/containerd
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client

And I know that Kubernetes offers interface to receive the runtime used on each client:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/find-out-runtime-you-use

But as mentioned I would like to know a programmatic way, preferably with golang. Because not every docker-client is a kubernetes Pod ;)

Comment: The ["Get system information" REST API call](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.42/#tag/System/operation/SystemInfo) includes a `DefaultRuntime` field; is that the information you need?  That's also exposed in the Go [`types.Info`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v23.0.5+incompatible/api/types#Info) structure.  (Why do you need to know this?)

Comment: One way is to go with API as @DavidMaze mentioned. If the task is simpler like some script, you could use docker tool: `docker inspect my-container-1 -f '{{ .HostConfig.Runtime }}'`.

Comment: I actually worry about the necessary API to use for each container-runtime.